# Finding the area between two curves with Integrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to solve and approximate the area between the two graphs. Right now, my functions are stored as

```
f[x_] := 3 Sin[x]
g[x_] := x - 1
```

and then I tried to integrate by evaluating

```
Integrate[Abs[f[x] - g[x]], x]
```

Instead of getting an answer, I just get the exact same thing I inputted

```
Integrate[Abs[f[x] - g[x]], x]
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 4):

Use `Assumptions`:

```
Integrate[Abs[f[x] - g[x]], x, Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or try `RealAbs` instead of `Abs`:

```
Integrate[RealAbs[f[x] - g[x]], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(They are equivalent antiderivatives.)

To get the area ***between*** the graphs, you need also to solve for the points of intersection.

```
area = Integrate[
 Abs[f[x] - g[x]], {x, Sequence @@ MinMax[x /. Solve[f[x] == g[x], x, Reals]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The area is approximately:

```
N[area]
(*  5.57475  *)
```

Comment: `RealAbs` is awesome to know about! :O

Answer (score 2):

You need to add assumptions, like this

```
 Integrate[Abs[f[x] - g[x]], x, Assumptions :> Element[x, Reals]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your functions

```
f[x_] := 3 Sin[x] 
g[x_] := x - 1
```

are real valued, you can use square root of square to parametrize the absolute value. This then gives:

```
Integrate[Sqrt[(f[x] - g[x])^2], x]
```

> (((-2 + x) x + 6 Cos[x]) Sqrt[(-1 + x - 3 Sin[x])^2])/(2 (-1 + x - 
>      3 Sin[x]))